# Exit Child Script without Exiting Parent Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a parent script that calls a child script. Within a child script is an `exit 1` command.

How do I exit the child script without stopping the parent script?

main code of parent_script

```
while read p; do
    report_name=`echo $p | awk -F "," '{print $1}'`
    script_check=`echo $p | awk -F "," '{print $7}'`

    var_check=`ls | grep "$report_name"* | head -1`
    if [[ $var_check != "" ]]; then
        if [[ $script_check == "suppress.sh" ]]; then
            $HOME_DIR/scripts/suppress.sh "$var_check" >> $HOME_DIR/scripts/log/suppress.sh.${DAY}.log
            echo "$?" error
        fi
    fi

    echo "$report_name"

done < $HOME_DIR/scripts/reports_dir_config
```

this loops through a lookup file and when condition is met it call the child script "suppress.sh"

child script contains code like this.

```
if [ blahblah ]
then
        call function
        exit 1
fi
```

I'm new with unix scripting so I'm learning as I code. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Better question: how do you manage to exit both?  I suspect you are sourcing the "child" rather than calling it, but you'll need to show some code.

Comment: I've updated my question with code. please feel free to check.

Comment: `suppress.sh` exiting will not cause the calling script to break the loop or exit. Something else is happening.  Try adding `set -x` to both scripts for more debugging output.

Comment: You can avoid the `echo $p | awk ...` lines and instead write `while IFS=, read report_name a b c d e script_check f; do `, letting read split the line.

Comment: thanks for the tip. ;) back to my question. I honestly can't see any reason for the exiting or breaking the loop aside from `exit 1`. I've commented this out and the parent script did not exit. I've also tried to change it to `exit 0`. parent script did not exit as well but I'm not sure yet as to what `exit 0` exactly does. I have to look it up.

Comment: Perhaps you have `set -e` set somewhere.  (Or `#!/bin/bash -e`).

Comment: oohhhhh... you are 100% right! damn. thank you! I've removed it on the parent script and seems to be working fine now.